# google analytics reporting api v4 not show isDataGolden

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am using Python example to do a query. Here is my requests:

```
body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
            'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2018-01-01', 'endDate': '2018-01-16'}],
            'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
            'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}],
            'samplingLevel' : 'LARGE'
        }]
      }
```

In the response, I checked and there are valid data from the response, however, I am looking for the "isDataGolden" field in the ReportData object and it's not present; only these fields are present 'totals', 'rowCount', 'rows', 'minimums', 'maximums'.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why field is not present? Google's documentation shows that it suppose to be there.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you sent `endDate` to `2018-01-10` (i.e. an end date that isn't too close to today)?

Comment: ah.. so I set the endDate to 'today' and nothing still. I then tried 2018-01-16, 2018-01-15 and still nothing. 

Then i changed it to 2018-01-14, then isDataGolden showed up and set to True.  

This is probably consisten with GA saying that they may have data latency up to 48hrs. 

While I expect it to be there and set to False, doesnt appear that it does that. Only appears and set to True when it's truly golden i guess.

Answer (score 0):

If any boolean field is absent, you can assume its value is false.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics):

> Note: When parsing the response body, if a boolean field is absent, you can assume its value is false. Only boolean fields with true value are shown in the response; for example, the isDataGolden field will be in the response if its value is true.